# Is Lambda Probe dead?

Tags: java, memory, tomcat, garbage-collection

Does anyone know where to get the **source** code for LambdaProbe?

Alternatively, does anyone know if the project could be moved to a community repository?

Besides the tool not being updated for over a year, the LambdaProbe website has been down since late September 2008.

Background: Lambda Probe is a useful tool for viewing stats on a running tomcat server. It used to be found at http://www.lambdaprobe.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site still seems to be pretty dead.  However, I've done some looking into available source code and release notes and here's everything I've found in regards to lambda probe.  I hope it helps!

Google cache search:
 site:www.lambdaprobe.org

Release notes:
http://209.85.173.104/search?q=cache:HB0527hDa5AJ:www.lambdaprobe.org/d/latest.shtml+release+site:www.lambdaprobe.org&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1

Lates Release Downloads:
http://209.85.173.104/search?q=cache:t5jXPCYgiCsJ:www.lambdaprobe.org/d/download.htm+download+1.7b+site:www.lambdaprobe.org&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1

http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.7/probe.1.7b.zip
http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.7/probe.1.7b.src.zip
http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.7/probe.1.7b-jb.zip

http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.6/probe.1.6.zip
http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.6/probe.1.6.src.zip
http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.6/probe.1.6-jb.zip

Answer (score 24):

There seems to be a fork of the project over at http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/

Comment: the psi-probe fork is much really more active than the dead project.

Comment: And now it has been moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/psi-probe/psi-probe)

Answer (score 2):

The project is currently hosted here: https://launchpad.net/lambdaprobe/+download

Also the files are alternatively hosted on Softpedia here: http://webscripts.softpedia.com/scriptDownload/Lambda-Probe-Download-69093.html

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about the status of the site, but it looks like you can grab a copy [over at Softpedia](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Server-Management/Lambda-Probe-69093.html).

Comment: That site has a link back to the WAR file, not the source.

Answer (score 1):

It has been forked and now is on GitHub here: https://github.com/psi-probe/psi-probe

Answer (score 0):

Actually the some part of the site is not working: it doesn't open the home page at http://www.lambdaprobe.org/, but the Softpedia external link points to http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.5/probe.1.5.0.1.zip and you can download from there.

Comment: I'm looking for the <b>source</b> code.

Answer (score 0):

Just played with the link Zloster sent and got version 1.6. Here it is
http://www.lambdaprobe.org/downloads/1.6/probe.1.6.zip 
Enjoy!